# Netlogo How to set heading to the average heading of target patches?

Tags: simulation, netlogo, agent

I have just started coding on Netlogo for a Masters project and trying to work out how to do something.

As part of a much larger model i am trying to programe a 'car' which can follow a route. The car needs to be able to follow a route which is somewhat complex/erratic as i plan to scan in a GIS layer for road networks and therefore cannot rely on nice 'neat' lines.

So far the 'car' follows these procedures to identify the next patch of 'road' it will 'drive' to.

```
breed [road]
breed [car]
patches-own [
road?
front-route
turn-route
reverse-route
nearest-front
nearest-turn
nearest-reverse]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-road 1 [
    set color gray
    setxy 0 0
  ]
  ask road [
    repeat 9 [
      set pcolor gray
      fd 1
    ]
    repeat 25 [
      set pcolor gray
      lt 10
      fd 1
    ]
    repeat 15 [
      set pcolor gray
      fd 1
    ]
    repeat 27 [
      set pcolor gray
      rt 9.8 
      fd 1
    ]
    repeat 9 [
      set pcolor gray
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
  ask road [
    die
  ]
  ask patches [set road? false]
  ask patches with [
    pcolor = gray][
    set road? true]
  create-car 1
  ask car [
    set color black]
end

to go
  ask car [
    follow-route]
end

to follow-route
  scan
  ifelse any? front-route [
    find-nearest-front]
    [ifelse any? turn-route [
      find-nearest-turn]
      [if any? reverse-route [
        find-nearest-reverse]
      ]
    ]
end

to scan
  set front-route other patches with [road?] in-cone 2 25
  set turn-route other patches with [road?] in-cone 2 180
  set reverse-route other patches with [road?] in-cone 1 360
end

to find-nearest-front
  set nearest-front max-one-of front-route [distance myself]
  face nearest-front
  fd 0.5
end

to find-nearest-turn
  set nearest-turn min-one-of turn-route [distance myself]
  face nearest-turn 
  fd 0.5
end

to find-nearest-reverse
  set nearest-reverse min-one-of reverse-route [distance myself]
  face nearest-reverse
  fd 0.5
end
```

The above code produces relatively satisfactory results however some 'shapes' of road cause it to misfire.

What i want the car to do is to set its heading to the mean heading change of patches identified in the 'scan' operation. Ideally this would allow my code to rely on one single 'scan' and 'route' operation as opposed to a seperate one for 'front routes' and 'turn routes'

I have played around with a few different commands but cant find a solution which works perfectly.

```
to-report average-front-road-heading
  let x-cord-front-road sum [pxcor] of front-route
  let y-cord-front-road sum [pycor] of front-route
  ifelse x-cord-front-road = 0 and y-cord-front-road = 0 [
    report heading ][
    report atan x-cord-front-road y-cord-front-road]
end

to-report average-turn-road-heading
  let x-cord-turn-road sum [pxcor] of turn-route
  let y-cord-turn-road sum [pycor] of turn-route
  ifelse x-cord-turn-road = 0 and y-cord-turn-road = 0 [
    report heading ][
    report atan x-cord-turn-road y-cord-turn-road]
end

to find-nearest-front
  set heading average-front-road-heading
  fd 0.5
end

to find-nearest-turn
  set heading average-turn-road-heading
  fd 0.5
end
```

The above code runs and appears to work for straight and gradually sloping roads but malfunctions on corners.

Thank you,

Harri

Comment: When it malfunctions on corners, is it because the search picks up the wrong patches, or because the conversion to a route is wrong? There are some flocking examples in the models library that might help. Also, have a look at the link-walking example in the code examples section of the library. If you can also construct links along pieces of road, then you can force the cars to move along those links, thereby staying on the road.